# Error 1009 after gotoAndStop - stage instance never gets added

Tags: flash, actionscript

I've been through the forums for hours (days?) searching on 1009 errors, but I remain stumped on this.  It seems very mysterious and I would LOVE some help if you have any ideas.

I have a single .swf that is 7 frames long - each frame represents a different "page" and you can switch pages through a menu widget in the top right corner.  The menu widget calls gotoAndPlay( "frame" ).

Everything works fine except when I switch from one particular frame to another.  Then, during initialization of the new frame (setting some visible properties on various items, in actionscript), I get the dreaded 1009 error on a specific stage instance, a dynamic text instance i_word.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- made sure the actionscript for the new frame starts with a stop() statement before starting initialization - no dice
- tried changing i_word into a movie_clip instead of dynamic text, made sure it was exported for actionscript - no difference.  (I also have 2 other dynamic text instances on the same page that don't seem to cause a problem)
- added an ENTER_FRAME listener when the new frame is loaded, in case the problem was a timing issue.  Put in a big if statement checking if i_word and other instances are not null before proceeding to initialization.  It never enters the if, because i_word NEVER gets added.  I added trace statements for all instances that are null, and it is the only one.  If I remove all references to i_word in my actionscript, everything else is not null, and things go forward.  The text for i_word even shows up on the screen in that case.
- tried renaming i_word - no dice
- tried deleting the layer i_word was on and adding a new layer - no dice

It feels like there is a serious Gremlin in my flash file somewhere.  Or maybe I'm missing something obvious.  Let me know if you have any ideas...I'd be so grateful.

Thank you!
Elambda

Comment: Could you please post some code? There's no way to know where you've erred without it.

Comment: Yes, you're right....I'll post some code.

Comment: Does the textfield exist in both frames, or is it limited to just the frame you are entering?  Is there another instance called i_word on any of the other frames?

Answer (score 0):

If you put an addEventListener command, you need to add a removeEventListener command so you don't get a 1009 error.
If the textfield does not exist on every frame, make sure you remove the event that goes with it.
example:

```
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hi);
function hi(Event:EVENT):void;
 {
datextfield.dosomething
}
```

then

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hi);
```

if this does not help do you mind posting code?